# How to use SharedPreferences to retrieve already selected photos

Tags: java, android

I want some assistance in being able to combine SharedPreferences with getPhotos I have selected. I am new with SharedPreferences and kind of not understand how it works.

So I made a SharedPreferencesManager:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private static final String APP_PREFS = "AppPrefsFile";
    private static final String  PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = "PickImageMultiple";

    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferencesManager instance;



    private SharedPreferencesManager(Context context) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public static synchronized SharedPreferencesManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new SharedPreferencesManager(context);

        return instance;
    }

    /* public int increaseClickCount() {
        int clickCount = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
        clickCount++;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, clickCount);
        editor.apply();
        return clickCount;
    } */

    public void putPhotos() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void getPhotos(){
         sharedPrefs.getInt(PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE, 0);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is keep all selected photos stored in shared preferences so that everytime I open the Glide it will show all selected photos. But it doesn't like the `imageUri = prefManager.getPhotos());`

```
public class PhotosGallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to show glide load image.
    ImageView photoGallery;
    Uri imageUri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos_gallery);

        SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(PhotosGallery.this);

        photoGallery = findViewById(R.id.photo_gallery);

        if (getIntent() != null) {             
            imageUri = prefManager.getPhotos());
            Glide.with(PhotosGallery.this).load(imageUri).into(photoGallery);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(PhotosGallery.this, "There are no images displayed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Can I have a little help on refactoring the SharedPreferences please?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your method:

```
public void getPhotos(){
    sharedPrefs.getInt(PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE, 0);
}
```

`void` - means it returns nothing
int - means you read an int value from prefs, but again, you assign it to nothing.

Normally, to get a number from prefs, you should write something like:

```
int myNumber = sharedPrefs.getInt(NAME, 0);
```

If you want to use it in a method, then, you should be:

```
public int getMyNumberFromPrefs(){
    return sharedPrefs.getInt(NAME, 0);
}
```

and then somewhere else:

```
int myNumber = prefManager.getMyNumberFromPrefs();
```

But then, if you read a int number from prefs, you cannot assign it to a Uri type variable.

So, you need to store a String variable in your prefs, and then parse Uri from a String....

But that's a whole chapter to learn and practice.

Comment: So this is my problem, based on the what I am trying to do, what should I really set PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE, should it be an int or a string, I am assuming because I need to use the URI it will be string as you mentioned so how to set the valriables to call on this?